# $scope issue on ngGridEventEndCellEdit event when i rollback data

Tags: angular-ui

I probably misunderstood something but here is my problem [on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUy9UcTNYkNfq4YMtt8E?p=preview).

I put the relevant code here anyway:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  var cellNameEditable = 
  '<cell-template model=COL_FIELD input=COL_FIELD entity=row.entity></cell-template>';

  var cellNameDisplay = 
  '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>';

  $scope.myData= [{"id":1,"code":"1","name":"Ain"},{"id":2,"code":"2","name":"Aisne"},{"id":3,"code":"3","name":"Allier"},{"id":4,"code":"5","name":"Hautes-Alpes"},{"id":5,"code":"4","name":"Alpes-de-Haute-Provence"},{"id":6,"code":"6","name":"Alpes-Maritimes"},{"id":7,"code":"7","name":"Ardèche"},{"id":8,"code":"8","name":"Ardennes"},{"id":9,"code":"9","name":"Ariège"},{"id":10,"code":"10","name":"Aube"}];
  $scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    multiSelect: false,
    enableCellSelection: true,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
    rowHeight: 100,
    columnDefs: [
        {field:'id', displayName:'Id', visible: false},
        {field:'code', displayName:'Code', enableCellEdit:true},
        {
            field:'name', displayName:'Name', enableCellEdit:true,
            cellTemplate: cellNameDisplay,
            editableCellTemplate: cellNameEditable
        }
      ]
    };
});

app.directive('cellTemplate', function () {

  var cellTemplate =
  '<div><form name="myForm" class="simple-form" novalidate>' +
  '<input type="text" name="myField" ng-input="localInput" ng-model="localModel" entity="entity" required/>' +
  '<span ng-show="myForm.myField.$error.required"> REQUIRED</span>' +
  'localModel = {{localModel}} localInput = {{localInput}} entity = {{entity}}' +
  '</form></div>';

  return {
    template: cellTemplate,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      localModel:'=model',
      localInput:'=input',
      entity:'=entity'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {

      $scope.$on('ngGridEventStartCellEdit', function (event) {

        console.log('cellTemplate controller - ngGridEventStartCellEdit fired');

        $scope.oldEntity = angular.copy(event.currentScope.entity);
        $scope.oldValue = angular.copy(event.currentScope.localModel);
      });

      $scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function(event) {

        console.log('ngGridEventEndCellEdit fired');

        if(event.currentScope.myForm.$valid) {
          if(!angular.equals($scope.oldEntity, event.currentScope.entity)) {
              alert('data saved !');
          }
        } else {

          $scope.localModel = angular.copy($scope.oldValue);
          $scope.localInput = angular.copy($scope.oldValue);
          $scope.entity = angular.copy($scope.oldEntity);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then explanations:

I have a ng-grid and based on [the official example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hy6Evh?p=preview) named "Excel-like Editing
Example" but with enableCellEditOnFocus option turned to false.

The cell "name" is defined in a directive containing a form to handle
data validation before updating the model.

I want to implement this behavior: When a user put invalid data, the
directive display error message and when the user leave the field, the
directive rollback data. If everything ok then I let the data updated.

The rollback part does not work. On the given plunker line 67 to 72 (last block on the code given here) it
fails to retore data. But my binding is with "=" so it should. Or maybe
because I am on the ngGridEventEndCellEdit event it breaks the links ?

I really don't understand why it fail.

So to reproduce my issue: enter in modification on a name cell, delete
all the data, REQUIRED is shown, then go out from the cell -> model is
not rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom template, you should **emit** ngGridEventEndCellEdit event.